# Chamada de função em arquivo externo no NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu tinha anteriormente um único arquivo chamado `aaa.js` em que existia a seguinte parte de código abaixo, e separei em partes:

```
const callback = (err, data, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('ERRO: ', err);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
};
const getQuery = (reqUrl) => {
    const url_parts = url.parse(reqUrl);
    return querystring.parse(url_parts.query);
};
const find = (req, res) => {
    const query = getQuery(req.url);
    MeuObjeto.find(query, (err, data) => callback(err, data, res));
};
const CRUD = {
    find
};
module.exports = CRUD;
```

Após fazer a separação de códigos para organizar melhor, criei quatro arquivos diferentes da seguinte maneira:

**aaa.js**

```
const find = require('./../actions/action-find')(MeuModel);
const CRUD = {
    find
};
module.exports = CRUD;
```

**find.js**

```
module.exports = (MeuModel) => {
    return (req, res) => {
        const query = getQuery(req.url); // <========= Como fica essa chamada?
        MeuModel.find(query, (err, data) => callback(err, data, res)); // <========= Como fica essa chamada?
    };
};
```

**callback.js**

```
module.exports = (err, data, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('ERRO: ', err);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

**get-query.js**

```
module.exports = (reqUrl) => {
    const url_parts = url.parse(reqUrl);
    return querystring.parse(url_parts.query);
};
```

**DÚVIDA**: Como faço para chamar as funções de "callback" e "get-query" a partir de dentro do arquivo "find.js" conforme apontado no comentário do código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const query = require('get-query')(url);
let callback = require('callback')(err, data, res);
MeuModel.find(query, (err, data) => callback;
```

Quando voce quer chamar outro arquivo voce usa o require com o nome dele (sem o .js pois esta chamando o modulo), e passa o parametro que eh usado na funcao do outro arquivo no parenteses seguinte.

Como funcoes podem ser armazenadas em variaveis, da um require na funcao e passa ela depois pro callback, esse segundo caso nao tenho 100% de certeza (se alguem puder confirmar com comentario agradeco)

Comment: Eu não consegui testar este seu exemplo para saber se dava certo. Montei alguns códigos para simular, mas nenhum funcionou, apesar de eu achar que sua resposta parece ser a correta. Não sei como resolver...

Comment: @wBB o que te impede de testar? bastaria trocar o codigo, usei suas variaveis

Comment: O que me impedia de testar era saber como testar da forma correta. Daí a abertura do tópico... Agora consegui: `const find = require('./action-get-query-http')(MeuValor, MeuSegundoParam);` e no arquivo `get-query` fica `module.exports = (Param1, Param2) => { return Param1 + ' ' + Param2; };`. Obrigado.